# How to make a div that updates with the most current donations

Tags: jquery, html, web, donations

i know html and css so the rest of the elements of my site i usually research and mix and mash together to get my desired outcome.

I'm creating a site and i would like to display the top 5 most recent donations.

i would like it to say the first name of the donator, 'just donated', the amount they donated, 'to', the organization they donated to.
EX: Anthony just donated $25.00 to March of Dimes.
(it would also be great if i could show how long ago they donated.)

I found a minecraft site that did this very well(http://minetown.net/donate  look at the right side of the page).

Thank you very much for your help!

-Anthony
(my first post)

Comment: Where is the donation information coming from?

Comment: you would need to use AJAX to get the recent donations, then update your page with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax calls to a webservice on your site that gives you the data about recent donations. The real question is to how often poll this service.  Thats your call.

Comment: i have heard of ajax, but i do not really understand it.

I'll learn up on it and come back to this question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply calculate the time passed since donation and display it beside the donations (Like 2 day(s) ago).

If you need to update the list while the user is viewing the page in realtime than you need to make the ajax call and get the latest list of donations and try to insert them in the page.